# Where is the TickCount() call?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Where is the TickCount() call? I have seen several threads on the web that recommend using the TickCount() call for iphone development. What do i need to "#include" to use this call? What framework is it in?

If not TickCount() what should I use to get milliseconds elapsed since the cpu started?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent](http://www.google.com/search?q=cfabsolutetimegetcurrent) is probably what You are looking for. (*Edit:* …Or maybe not. Do You really need the time from CPU start, or do You just want to measure time in ms?)

Comment: Thanks! No I do not really need the time from CPU start, just need elapsed time in MS.

Comment: Yep, then this function is exactly it. It returns CFAbsoluteTime, which is a double in disguise. If you type your variable CFAbsoluteTime instead of double, Xcode will decorate the number as time value when showing the value bubble in debugger.

Answer (score 2):

In my header file, I add the following:

```
#include <time.h>

@interface myAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
  ...
  clock_t initStart, initStop;
}
```

In my implementation file, I add the following:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
  srandom(time(NULL));
  initStart = clock();
  ...
}

...

- (void) applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
  initStop = clock();
  NSLog(@"Elapsed CPU time: %f", (double)(initStop - initStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  ...
}
```

You could move these calls around your app as needed, to measure elapsed time.

Comment: Thank you! Only reason I am gonna use CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent is that Apple used CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent in their GLPaint example.